# What 70's/80's freewheel threading is most common in central or eastern Europe?

Tags: hub, freewheel

Just interested to know?

For example, if an 80's steel frame road bike in Europe came with Suzue high flanged hubs (94mm spacing front and 126mm rear), what type of freewheel threading would be expected?

Specifically, Suzue Sat. No. 5 (94mm) front and Suzue Sat. No. 6 (126mm) rear.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Suzue is a Japanese company. The [threading for the freewheel is ISO](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=e3914c57-e318-4b55-8f6b-063301e5ad03&Enum=110) for the Suzue Sat. No. 6.

In general, its quite easy to measure these things by just measuring the [thread pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screw_thread#Lead.2C_pitch.2C_and_starts). Aside from French and Metric BMX freewheels, the rest of the freewheel standards (English, USA, ISO, Italian) are all 24 TPI and about 1.375", and are effectively interchangable.